# Globally hide navigation bar in SwiftUI project

Tags: ios, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to globally hide the navigation bar, so I don't need to do `.navigationBarHidden(true)` on each view's `onAppear`.

Is there a global way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Your question does not make a whole lot of sense. The line of code is a hardcoded value/line. How does `onAppear` get involved? Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension of NavigationController to handle its visibility on global level like this

```
extension UINavigationController{
    open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
}
```